# Numpy salt and pepper image on color region?

Tags: numpy, image-processing, machine-learning, dataset

I have tons of images that look like the following:

[image]

I want to add random black and white pixels (salt and pepper) to those images, but only within the colored circle. The black border around the circle must remain `[0, 0, 0]`. The purpose for this is to augment a machine learning dataset.

#### Question

How can this be done using Numpy?

Comment: And what is you problem - determine circle region? Or its shape/position is constant?

Comment: All of the above. How to add random, sharp noise (pixels that are either very dark or very bright), and making sure they only get added to the colored part of the image. The noise could be added everywhere, but then I'd need a way to overlay that outer border to ensure that area is always black.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way - generate random coordinates in given rectangle and check whether pixel at this position is not black. If not, change its color to random choice of black and white. Pseudocode:

```
while saltcount < limit:
   rx = random(width)
   ry = random(height)
   c = pixel[ry][rx]
   if (c != 0):
       pixel[ry][rx] = 0xFFFFFF * random(2)
       saltcount++
```

This method rejects about 21% of tryouts (black area ratio for perfectly inscribed circle) but is very simple. If you know circle parameters, generate points only inside the circle:

```
x = cx + r * sqrt(t) * cos(2 * Pi * a)
y = cy + r * sqrt(t) * sin(2 * Pi * a)
```

where `cx,cy,r` are circle center coordinates and radius, `t` and `a` are randoms in range `0..1`

If you need to find circle at the picture, you can make grayscale picture or use any channel of r,g,b and use Hough transform to discover circle parameters.